# Json request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, response

I am just beginner on java script and JSON and never had done any work in these before. My employer has just asked me to create the basic POC of these.

**Scenario:**
I have a REST API and when i call it, it returns back response in JSON format. 

**Need to To:**
Create a HTML page and use javascript to call that REST API and capture JSON response and print in the same HTML page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadMe() {
       loadJSON('http://myrestAPI');
   }
        function loadJSON(url) {
            //Help me here to capture the response and print in html page. 
         }
</script>
```

I would appreciate your help. This might be simple, but for me i have no idea because i never have done anything similar in java script and json. I goggled but could not find anything.

Thanks,
chota

Comment: no i cannot. just javascript.

Comment: jQuery IS just javascript :P Is there a reason that you can't use it? I'd wonder about an employer who explicitly told me that I couldn't use OS packages that make me more efficient in my work (barring legal reasons of course)...

Comment: jQuery *is* javascript...are you sure?

Comment: jQuery is mighty bulky and sometimes you need to develop without it. Good example of a situation like that would be a userscript, or any situation where you only need to do one thing. That said, I am almost always using jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is a whopping 26kB. Given that even google's simple homepage is 260+kB, I'd say "mighty bulky" is a bit of an overstatement.

Answer (score 2):

```
 function SendRequest(MSG)
 {
  var objJSON = {
   "msg" : MSG
  };
  var strJSON = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(objJSON));
  new Ajax.Request("ReceiveJSON.jsp",
   {
    method: "post",
    parameters: "strJSON=" + strJSON,
    onComplete: Respond
   });
 }

function Respond(REQ)
 {
  document.getElementById("ResponseDiv").innerHTML=REQ.responseText;
 }
```

Comment: This is very complex for me to understand

Comment: Can you please explain which part you couldnt understand

Comment: Ajax object doesn't exist in my browser

Answer (score 1):

If you view your REST request response, the JSON might be something like this

```
{
    "users": [
        {"first": "Peter",
         "last": "Griffin"}
    ],
    "books": [
        {"title": "Design Patterns",
         "author": "The Gang of Four",
         "year": 1995}

    ]

}
```

This rest query result can be loaded as a javascript array object

```
<script language="javascript">

var resultObj = <Result of your REST url + query pasted here>;

</script>
```

Then,

you access it in your html with javascript blocks like

```
document.write(resultObj.users[0].first)
```

which would return `'Peter'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON(url, null, function (data) { .... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Praneeth has the simple javascript answer. If you can use jquery (and there really is no reason you cannot) it gets way easier:

```
<div id="response"></div>
$.get(url, function(data) {
  $('#response').append(data.property);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to append the data to the div.  You could have a <p> element inside the div and append to that instead.

Comment: My bad.  It does make sense and works.  Didn't think it through.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete working example using jQuery that should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="response">
    <p id="responseParagraph">Base text</p>
</div>

<script>
    $.getJSON('http://myrestAPI',
        function(data) {
            $('#responseParagraph').append("<p>"+data.responseMessage+"</p>");
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```